Break Permission at Folder Level of a Library with more than 100k items
I need to understand the limitation of unable to break permissions at folder, library and list with more than 100k items.
Suppose I have library which has more than 100k items. So as per the limitation mentioned by Microsoft I will not be able to break permission at the library level since it has crossed 100k items.
However my library is well organized into folders and sub-folders. My question is - will I be able to break permission at the folder/sub-folder level of that library with more than 100k items. The folder/sub-folder level don't have more than 100 items.

As per the Microsoft official documentation SharePoint limits - Items in lists and libraries,

A list can have up to 30 million items and a library can have up to 30 million files and folders. When a list, library, or folder contains more than 100,000 items, you can't break permissions inheritance on the list, library, or folder. You also can't reinherit permissions on it. However, you can still break inheritance on the individual items within that list, library, or folder, up to the maximum number of unique permissions in the list or library (see the next section).

Next section is this, SharePoint limits - Unique security scopes per list or library:

The supported limit of unique permissions for items in a list or library is 50,000. However, the recommended general limit is 5,000.

So, if you have less than 100 items in your folder/sub-folder, you should be able to break permissions on that specific folder/sub-folder and use unique permissions.

I agree with Ganesh Sanap. If you have less than 100,000 items in your folder/sub-folder, you can break permissions on that specific folder/sub-folder and use unique permissions. However, it is still advisable not to exceed 5000, otherwise unpredictable errors may occur.
